# what the aquatic creature need in order to live or survive in my acid water?

Tags: biology, creature-design, xenobiology, fauna, sea-creatures

inspire by xenomorph acid blood from alien movies.

so the water either rivers, lakes, and oceans in my world or some of the regions is highly acidic because some of the dirt or stone minerals content mix with the water make it into corrosive acid that can corrode or melt normal skin tissue upon contact, and during prolong contact it can melt the normal flesh and damage or corrode metals especially iron/steel, and it also can rapidly damage normal wood especially wooden plank not native from this environment, but its not in the point to boil the water or increase/decrease the water temperature by itself nor creating dangerous gas, and rain water is safe though not acidic or not that high or corrosive.

the water also have color (not decide the color yet or will ends up add it in or not later) because some of the dirt or stone and water plant contain some natural dye minerals but its pretty safe for the creature, also the soil outside of the water is in permafrost state (not decide is it mix with the same acid or just normal ice yet, but eitherway even if it contain acid it quite small and not in liquid state so i dont think it will be dangerous or harmful), i add this in case its considered an important information to make better/clearer answer.

so far i assume the water creature can protect their skin or flesh by covering themselves with carapace and other type of shell like crustaceans and Bothriolepis fish, but i dont know how to protect their gills and eyes.

another is base of human stomach using mucus, but i dont know is it effective outside the body or for external organs (at least i think it can protect some of the internal organs or the flesh parts inside of the mouth) but i assumed the mucus can also block the gills making the creature unable to breath or can even still make the creature can see at all because of the mucus covering the eyes.

the aquatic creature not necessary need eyes but i add it just to see the visibility to protect that organs.

also the aquatic creature is form from natural evolution, not from genetic modification by inteligent lifeforms.

and so i want to know what water creature like fish and crustaceans like crab need in order to survive in this environment especially to their gills and eyes, and would there be need a dfferent biological solution or evolution between plain water and salt water.

also curious to see a better solution outside of exoskeleton or shell type ( not exclude it for answer just want to see is there a better possible  solution outside of that.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most generic answer? Lots of food, and proton pumps.

There are Earthling extremophile organisms that can thrive in highly acidic environments. Generally, they do it by carefully excluding the acids from their intracellular spaces--how acidic the external environment is then doesn't matter. Some of this can be accomplished with purely chemical means, by synthesizing as part of their metabolism basic and pH buffer compounds to counteract the effects of any acids that may diffuse through the cell membrane, but the primary defense is the proton pump. All Earthling cells have these mechanisms already; they are, for example, critical components of mitochondria, which set up proton gradients to power ATP synthase. It is, therefore, a relatively simple matter to repurpose that machinery to just continually pump stray protons out of the cell entirely to keep the pH down.

The catch is that this is a very energy intensive process. A complex multicellular organism with a large surface area exposed to the acidic environment, especially one that is expressly designed for exchanging dissolved materials with said environment (like, say, gills, or roots and leaves), will be expending a significant fraction of its total energy budget on Not Dissolving.

There is thus a significant advantage to simply altering ones biochemistry to tolerate the acidic conditions from the get-go. And seeing as how life is likely to *start* in the seas, or at least in groundwater (unless this is originally-alien life that has adapted itself to this world), that seems likely to have happened. Exactly how such adaptation would occur, however, depends on specifically which acids are present; different acids do not attack all other chemical substances equally. Perhaps, for example, your world's surface waters have a high concentration of sulfuric acid; in that case, you don't need to worry about *dissolving* so much as having all of your organic molecules forcibly dehydrated, reducing you to a hot pile of activated charcoal and nitrogen gas. Silicones with small organic side-chains, however, are not subject to the same kind of chemical attack by sulfuric acid--so maybe life on this world is just based on silicones in sulfuric acid solution, and actually has the *opposite* problem of keeping excess fresh water out of its cells! (Which would cause rapid heating from the heat of solvation and burst cell membranes from osmotic pressure.) A heavy acid like sulfuric acid would work especially well for your scenario, since rainwater, while still acidic from our point of view, would be naturally distilled and end up quite pure in comparison with sea water (just like our seas are filled with salt, but our rain *isn't*--and we Earthling organisms whose Latest Universal Common Ancestor evolved in sea water, do indeed have to worry about maintaining osmotic balance and not letting too much fresh water into our cells all at once, so that isn't even all that exotic of a concern in basic principles).

If, for example, your world is rich in nitric or hydrochloric acid instead, the necessary biochemical adaptations would be rather different.

Comment: @Chickensarenotcows Quite the opposite--you'd only get a lot of sulfuric acid if there's spare oxygen to go around. I mean, you *could* get a world where there's enough oxygen to make sulfur trioxide, but not a lot left over, but it's hardly certain. And if you did, the oxygen in that sulfuric acid would be just as, if not more, important as a metabolic oxidizer as the sulfur--i.e., you're looking at sulfate reduction, producing water and waste sulfur, not sulfur reduction, producing hydrogen sulfide.

Comment: On further reflection, while microorganisms (and plants, which can recycle the material on-site) may reduce sulfate all the way to elemental sulfur grains, if the environment is anoxic and complex heterotrophic organisms rely on sulfate reduction for respiration, I would expect them to *only* reduce sulfuric acid down to water and sulfur dioxide, since that can be more easily excreted in gas or solvated liquid phase.

Comment: I be fascinated how a metabolic system might pan-out in such a world, or rather a set of metabolic systems forming an ecosystem. Energy intensive, as you say, somewhat speculative though. That's for another question.

Comment: @Chickensarenotcows Should you wish to ask such a question, I'd be happy to pull out my copy of Stephen Gillett's _Worldbuilding_ and expound on the section about sulfur worlds....

Comment: thanks it help me a lot, but what if the proton pump only cover certain parts like gilss or the eyes not entire body? will it still require quite high energy intensive? also are the silicon fish edibel (what reaction if they out of the acid water or even being cooked?) and are the rainwater drinkabel? because my human is just normal human that decide to make colony there,  does this work for plant too? i kinda think proton pump would not be good for passive lifeform like plant and i want it to be still made of wood or plantbase, i actually prepare second question beforehand should i post it?

Comment: @Chickensarenotcows i never though of that, since they probably immune to acid, i wonder what method of digestion possible for a type of creature like this too (at least thats what i get from what you say), but i think i leave it for you to make or post that question since you seems more an expert on this subject, and my english and grammar suck anyway.

Comment: @LiJun Yes, it is possible to save energy by only using proton pumps for pH maintenance on exposed tissues; you needn't even necessarily use it on eyes, if you have, e.g., compound eyes with silica corneas. Silicone-based organisms would not be edible for us; it would be massive good luck if they merely turned out to not be incredibly toxic. You'd get as much nutrition from them as from eating a silicone oven mitt. The rainwater would probably not be drinkable as-is, but it would be relatively simple to make it safe. And yes, all the same mechanisms would work for plants.

Comment: @LiJun Organisms that maintain pH with proton pumps stop being immune when they are killed, so regular digestion would work just fine, providing you don't swallow your food live (and even then, that doesn't mean your stomach doesn't have other ways to kill it). Organisms that are biochemically adapted to a specific environment acid would still be vulnerable to *other* acids. And plenty of Earthling organisms don't even bother to make use of acid digestion, anyway; instead, you can rely entirely on enzymatic action to digest food.

Comment: care to elaborate how to processing or distilled the rainwater to be safe to drink? also if the tree for example get cut down it wont produce proton pump anymore right? since i also want to make wooden structure or the plank that still immune from the acid, and seems alot of incompatibility for my tree description, i have prepare the question beforehand though (not post it yet).

Comment: after googling a bit i found teak wood contain high silica seems like silicon is a possibility to me for my plantbase too, or combine  both so theres an edibel parts not contain silicon, or to protect against my acid it need to be made entirelly of silicon? wont it get overheat if getting water too?

Comment: @LiJun Simply neutralizing the rainwater with a basic chemical would suffice. Sodium hydroxide or sodium bicarbonate (i.e., baking soda) would work fine; you'd end up with sodium sulfate in solution (if you go with sulfuric acid), but that's non-toxic. Hydrochloric acid is also not a big deal (you just end up with salt water). Nitric acid would present more difficulties, as nitrate salts are toxic to humans.

Comment: @LiJun If you don't want to go with silicone (note the 'e') based biology, and just rely on proton pumping so you can keep normal organic biology that might be human edible, it would still make sense for the equivalent of "woody" plants to have a high-silica structure, with silica fibers standing in for cellulose and lignin; proton pumping doesn't really help to protect extracellular structures like that anyway, and as you have discovered there is precedent in Earthling biology for using silica as a structural material--in diatoms, sponges, grasses, and trees.

Comment: sorry to bother you again but can silica withstand sulfuric acid ? or it must be made of silicone ? i try to google it but i cant found any clear information regarding it.

Comment: @LiJun Yes, it can. Silica is the primary component of glass, which is used to store sulfuric acid. It's a fine material for making structural components out of, but it's pretty rigid and has a very boring crystal structure, so you want the more versatile silicones to perform the biochemical functions for which we use complex organic molecules.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley hey sorry to bother you again, i have make a question base on your answer to get more elaborate detail regarding silicone plants, i hope you can give an answer in here [what would a silicone base plants especially tree look like?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/154204/what-would-a-silicone-base-plants-especially-tree-look-like)